# The difference between jre / jre-1.7.0 / jre-1.7.0-openjdk / jre-openjdk /jre-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8.x86_64

Tags: java, tomcat

### 1. My Query & what I reseached

After I installed JDK for Linux X64 (8u181-b13), the directory of /usr/lib/jvm included the following symbolic link of jre's.

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUVGB.jpg)

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   21 May 29  2020 jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   27 May 12  2020 jre-1.7.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   35 May 12  2020 jre-1.7.0-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0_openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   54 May 12  2020 jre-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8.x86_64 -> java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   27 May 12  2020 jre-1.8.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   35 May 12  2020 jre-1.8.0-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   51 May 12  2020 jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64 -> java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   29 May 12  2020 jre-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk
```

My query what is the difference of these versions, and which should be specifed during installation of Tomcat8.5.55 .

```
jre
jre-1.7.0
jre-1.7.0-openjdk
jre-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8.x86_64
jre-openjdk
```

As far as I searched, my understanding of each sybolic link as follows.

#### jre

-Is a sybolic link pointing to

```
/etc/alternatives/jre
```

-It is only including JRE and does not include JDK

-The difference I found from jre-1.7.0 and jre-1.8.0 is that this jre is including "jjs" which is a javascript library which is depreciated now

#### jre-1.7.0

-Is a sybolic link pointing to

```
/etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0
```

-It is only including JRE and does not include JDK

#### jre-1.7.0-openjdk

-Is a sybolic link pointing to

```
/etc/alternatives/jre_1.7.0_openjdk
```

-It is only including JRE and does not include JDK, only installing the JRE part from the open JDK.

#### jre-openjdk

-Is a sybolic link pointing to 
/etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk

-It is an open source implementation of JavaSE and this includes JDK.

### 2. Background of query & What I want to do

I am now trying to install Tomcat 8.5.55 in CentOS 7.I am asking this question because, when I create tomcat service file, there is a line which specifies the JAVA_HOME, and I couldn't figure out whether to give "jre" or "jre-1.7.0" or "jre-1.8.0" in this path.

```
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
```

[Entire tomcat.service file]

```
# Systemd unit file for tomcat
[Unit]
Description=Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
After=syslog.target network.target
 
[Service]
Type=forking
 
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre
Environment=CATALINA_PID=[Tomcat Home Directory]/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=[Tomcat Home Directory]
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=[Tomcat Home Directory]
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'
 
ExecStart=[Tomcat Home Directory]/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/bin/kill -15 $MAINPID
 
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1hc9.jpg)

Comment: Those are different versions with different features, which is one discussion. In terms of which Tomcat to use that depends on a variety of factors, and he's a pretty broad question. The functionality of stack overflow really works best with narrow specific questions. I think your best bet is to probably research your questions a little bit through Google, then ask specific questions as they come up here on stack overflow.

Comment: @Don Branson
Thanks for your comment. Yes, I could understand that jre-1.7.0 and jre-1.8.0 are different versions, but how about plain "jre"? I was searching google for the difference between "jre" and "jre-1.7.0" but I couldn't find it, so I am asking here.

And following your advice, I added more details of the question to narrow the case. My Tomcat version, and what exactly I am stuck on.

Comment: The jre versions are for running code only, It doesn't have any of the tools for writing code. The jre with the version is a specific version, and the one without a version is most likely a softlink to your active version.

Comment: Once you've picked a tomcat with the features you want, or picked the latest version, it will tell you which jdk or JRE you need to run it.

Comment: @Don Branson Thank you very much again for your kind comment.
Regarding to the following point, I checked inside the directory which each symbolic link is pointing to, and for each directory there is "bin" & "lib" folder, but the items inside "jre" & "jre-1.7.0" & "jre-1.8.0" were all different.  
> and the one without a version is most likely a softlink to your active version.

"jre" & "jre-1.7.0" where very close except that "jre" having the "jjs" which is a javascript library which is depreciated now, so I thought this is very old.

And "jre-1.8.0" had way more stuff ->Continue next

Comment: which I felt there was a major change from "jre-1.7.0" to "jre-1.8.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Apache Tomcat versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) page lists the Java versions that are compatible for various Tomcat versions.  It says that Tomcat 8.5.x requires Java 7 *or later*.

However, Java 7 is end-of-life, so Java 8 is advisable.

---

> I understand that "jre-1.7.0","jre-1.8.0" are different versions, but how about the difference between "jre" and "jre-1.7.0"?

The `jre` entry in that directory is a symbolic link.  It ultimately resolves to the JRE version that has been selected as the default using the `update-alternatives` command.

You can figure it out either by following the symlinks by hand or by running `update-alternatives --display java`

It is probably advisable to use either the `jre-1.7.0` or `jre-1.8.0` symlink so that your Tomcat service uses the *latest* Java 7 or 8 installation installed by the package manager.  (Java 8 is still getting updates ...)

---

As to the specific differences, it is not possible to give a definitive answer.  The design of the symlinks is done by the people who implemented the OpenJDK packaging for your Linux distro.  It may be different across different distros (e.g. Ubuntu vs RHEL).  It could even change between versions of the same distro, though that would be "unfortunate".

However, I would assume that something that is labelled as a "jre" is only a JRE.  If I want / need a JDK, I would make sure that I had installed the "jdk" package, and then use the corresponding symlink for a "jdk".

<sup>The JRE versus JDK distinction is going to become a thing of the past.  From Java 9 onwards, Oracle Java and OpenJDK Java builds only come in JDK varieties.  As of "Hirsute", Ubuntu distro packaging is still making the distinction between JRE and JDK packages for OpenJDK, but my guess is that at some point the Ubuntu Java packaging maintainers will decide it is not worth it.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. I researched again and added my understanding for each versions. If there are any misunderstandings, it would be happy if you could point it out.

Comment: The information you found will be Linux distribution specific; i.e. it may be different in a different distro or even a different release of the distro.  But the intention of the symlinks is to allow you isolate your scripts from Java version changes, *or not*, depending on your requirements.  So, basically, it is *up to you* to decide how tightly you want to "bind" your Tomcat installation to a Java version.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Based on your advice I understood as follows.
"jre" : non-tight "bind" to the Java version since it will be the latest ?
"jre-1.7.0" :  tight "bind" to Java7 which is out dated so this should not be used now.
"jre-1.8.0" :  tight "bind" to Java8

Comment: Yea.  That's about right.  Alternatively you could bind even more tightly; e.g. to "jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64"

Comment: Thank you very much again. Your comment solved my query, thanks for teaching me a lot.